# Можно ли автоматизировать добавление UDID в учетку разработчика?

Tags: ios, xcode

Имеется учетка Apple Developer Program для индивидуального разработчика.
Распространяю приложение по схеме Ad-Hoc.
Каждый раз, когда появляется новый пользователь, приходится добавлять UDID его устройства в аккаунт, генерировать новый Provisioning Profile и внедрять его в архив (конечный ipa-файл), для того, чтобы пользователь смог установить это приложение.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: нет. нельзя автоматизировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упростить себе жизнь можно с помощью следующего инструмента: 
https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign

1. В аккаунте разработчика добавляем UDID в профайл
2. Скачиваем профайл
3. Запускаем iReSign
4. Указываем .ipa файл, который нужно переподписать
5. Указываем скачанный профайл
6. Указываем сертификат разработчика для Distribution
7. Нажимаем ReSign! и - вуаля!
8. Переподписанный .ipa файл выкладываем на сервер для Ad-Hoc

Также для автоматизации можно использовать инструмент https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane